What is the correct way to obtain an instance of the authenticated user if I'm using a JWT
I want to do so it's not necessary to pass the id or username in the request.
I was doing it like this:
// In the controller
@DeleteMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteStudent(@RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String authHeader) {
    studentService.deleteEstudiante(authHeader); // Pass the token into the service
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
// In the service
public void deleteStudent(String authHeader) {
    String token = jwtService.getTokenFromAuthorizationHeader(authHeader).orElseThrow(
            () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token")
    );

    String email = jwtService.getUsernameFromToken(token); // Get the subject
    
    // Rest of the logic where I search the user by email in the repository and I delete it
}

But I figured that's wrong. Which is the correct way?

I can't say which approach is right, as I think this depends on individual preferences or requirements.
In my case, I use a JWT filter as shown below:
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = tokenParser.resolveToken(request);

        if (token != null && !token.isBlank()) {
            if (blackListRepository.existsByAccessToken(token)) {
                throw new TokenExpiredException();
            }

            Authentication authentication = tokenParser.authentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

Using this code, I register the following filter and execute it on a page that can only be accessed by logged-in users. The filter verifies the token and registers the current user in Spring Security's SecurityContextHolder.
And then, I use the following method:
   public User getUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        AuthDetails authDetails = null;
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof AuthDetails) {
            authDetails = (AuthDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        if (authDetails == null || authDetails.getPhone() == null) {
            throw new BasicException(ErrorCode.TOKEN_NOT_VALID);
        }

        return userRepository.findByPhone(authDetails.getPhone()).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
    }

I retrieve the user from the SecurityContextHolder and use it.
